# How to draw a simple rectangle with base R

Tags: r, graphics, rectangles

I would like to draw a rectangle with **base R only**:

Rectangle: width= 2.5 cm and height = 1 cm

Desired output:

[image]

This is in principle possible with `drawBox`, but I am looking for a base R solution:

```
library(draw)
drawBox(x =1.5, y = 4, width = 2.5, height = 1)
```

Comment: See `help("rect")`

Comment: Already tried: This code in the example: `plot(c(100, 200), c(300, 450), type= "n", xlab = "", ylab = "")
rect(100, 300, 125, 350) # transparent` gives a rectangle in coordinate system. I just want a rectangle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just create an empty plot first, then use the base R function `rect()`:

```r
plot(NULL, axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "", xlim = c(0, 2.5), ylim = c(0, 1))
rect(xleft = 0, xright = 2.5, ybottom = 0, ytop = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. But it is not what I am thinking of. Nevertheless I vote up. Maybe I can't explain what I want. In essence it should be a rectangle in the mentioned size that I can use as object and put it somewhere else!

Answer (score 1):

What about the following:

```
par(mar = rep(0.2,4))
plot(NA, xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1), axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")
box()
```

then embed this in a pdf with specified size.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. But it is not what I am thinking of. Nevertheless I vote up. Maybe I can't explain what I want. In essence it should be a rectangle in the mentioned size that I can use as object and put it somewhere else!

Comment: What do you mean with "somewhere else"?

Comment: Please see here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66413386/r-markdown-reduce-the-space-between-two-plots-in-pdf-output-document> It seems not possible to draw a rectangle, put it on left upper corner and then (without a huge white space) see the next object. The question is about pdf but the same is with html. I thought maybe this due the `draw` package and therefore asked this question. But with both solutions it is same moreover both solutions here gibe to big rectangles. Nevermind and thank you for your valuable time...

Comment: Hmm, not sure if I understand your problem, bit you may try package [gridBase](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gridBase), that allows flexible placement of graphic objects.